# Max Resistance in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is resistance percentage calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69584/how-is-resistance-percentage-calculated)

What is the Max Resistance you can get in diablo 3? I couldn't find anything on the topic or any duplicates here.

Comment: There's some more information about resistances in another thread [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69584/how-is-resistance-percentage-calculated).

Comment: There is no maximum.  There is a reasonable limit, though, so if you want to edit your question to something like [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75547/what-is-the-highest-critical-chance-and-critical-damage-that-is-possible-through), it could be answerable.

Comment: I might as well as close this question than. The one @GnomeSlicE sent me pretty much explains it for me. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @Samjus: I've undeleted your question. We actually prefer to keep duplicates to make it easier for other users to find the original question. When this is closed it will link to the original question.

Comment: @Wipqozn I will have to remember that for next time.

Comment: There actually is a maximum attainable from gear based off mods - 1620 (Must be monk with One with Everything passive). If you include legendaries you can get a little higher from dualwielding 2x wizardspikes.