# Can a certain elemental resistance get high enough for it to heal you?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to increase a resistance to a point where that element actually starts to heal you? For example, if you get very high poison resistance, will it eventually start healing you at a certain point..or does the resistance amount max out at a certain point. I read a comment in chat where "poison" was healing him, so I was curious about this.

Comment: Related, perhaps dupe: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69584/how-is-resistance-percentage-calculated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, due to diminishing returns on resistance values (each additional point is worth less) you can not reach 100% resistance to any element through that. I believe it's close to impossible to reach above 85% or so.

That said, there are certain legendary items that will make you immune to a certain element and instead cause that element to heal you. For example:

[Countess Julia's Cameo](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/countess-julias-cameo) - Arcane

[Mara's Kaleidoscope](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maras-kaleidoscope) - Poison

Comment: just to round the list out, star of azkaranth (suuuper rare) - fire, talisman of aranoch - cold, xephirian amulet - lightning and fwiw getting to 85% is pretty easy as a wizard.

Comment: Saying that resistance is has diminishing returns is misleading. Yes, getting from 70% to 80% takes less all res than getting from 80% to 90%. However, getting from 80 to 90 is more mitigation than going from 70 to 80. If you take 70% reduced, then you take 30% damage. At 80% you take 20%, meaning from 70 to 80 you take 1/3 less damage. Going from 80 to 90, is going from 20% to 10% damage, which is 1/2 less damage. The math actually works out that the Effective HP to All resistance ratio is exactly linear, and there is no diminishing returns.

Comment: @Cruncher While your point on Effective HP is true, the question is about reaching 100%, not increasing EHP. And percent-wise, returns are very much diminishing.

Comment: Percent-wise, returns are very much irrelevant.

Comment: All good points.  Thanks!  Sad thing is, I had the Star of Azkaranth at one point and sold it...I had no idea it was that rare. Hopefully I get it again later.